# css less - is it possible to check for element size?

Tags: css, less

I have few thumbnail image of users and their image can be portrait or wide.

I wish the thumbnails to be in a circle without lose the aspect ratio of it.

So I created a container for each image like that:

```
<div class='container'>
  <img src='' ... />
</div>
```

With this css:

```
.container {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;

  img {
    width: inherit;
  }
}
```

it works fine with portrait images because the image width inherit from the container.

The problem now is to adapt the same to wide images... I should replace the `width` with `height` in order to let in work as expected.

There is a better solution of mine?

Or there is a way with Less to achieve at this?

Answer (score 0):

You should leave the `width`/`height` unset and set the `max-width`/`max-height` to `100%`.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

This will only downscale images though, not upscale.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Using `max-*` I have always to declare: `max-width: 100%` for portrait images and `max-height: 100%` for wide images. It still need a `controller`...

Answer (score 0):

`width: fit-content; height: fit-content;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container > img{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src='http://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2015/12/duckduckgo-logo-wordmark4-1920.png' alt='duck power'>
</div>
```